# Why does this C++ code not work for negative integers?

Tags: c++, integer

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int x;
int y;
int z;
int main ()
{
    cout << "x=";
    cin >> x;
    z = x;
    y = 0;
    while(z > 0)
    {
        (z = z / 10);
        (y = y + 1);
    }
    while(z < 0)
    {
        (z =- z);
        (z = z / 10);
        (y = y + 1);
    }
    cout << "cifre=" << y;
}
```

It seems to work just fine for positive integers, but not for negative ones, and I don't understand why. Can someone explain? It has to count the number of digits...

Comment: Define _'works fine'_ please. Show inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: The answer lies in the eye of the debugger.

Comment: `(z=z/10)` Please remove `(` and `)`, it's annoying.

Comment: What is this program supposed to do?
Can you tell us the expected output?

Comment: What language(s) are you used to? The format of your source looks odd and illogical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not "work" for negative integers probably since the sign of `z` is flipped in each iteration in your `while (z<0)` loop. Hence the loop will stop after the first iteration, with `y` being 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
cout <<"x=";
cin >>x;
z=x;
y=0;
if(z<0)
    z=-z;
while(z>0)
{
    z=z/10;
    y=y+1;
}
cout <<"cifre=" <<y;
```